# Updating variables each submit click without javascript

Tags: php

I'm trying to cycle through my photo gallery with next / previous buttons. When the user clicks on a photograph it enlarges it. When they click next it should go to the next photo. When the user clicks on the submit button immediately after selecting the photo it will enlarge the next photo. However when they click submit (next) again it doesn't update the $index variable. I know the reason is because once its set the first time the `isset($_POST['myNext')` evaluates to false. So how can I update $index each time they click on the button. I don't want to use javascript for this because it should be possible with PHP. I also don't want to just copy and paste some JS i don't understand. I've looked online for answers but have found nothing without JS. I've omitted the code to scan the directory with the images. Thank you.

```
 <?php

for($i = 0; $i < count($thumbArray); $i++)
{
    $currentIndex = $thumbArray[$i];
    echo '<div class = "img"> <a href ="?original_selection='.$currentIndex.'"> <img src="'.$dir.$thumbArray[$i].'" alt="Picture" height = "100" width = "100" /> </a> </div>';
}

if(isset($_GET['original_selection'])) 
{
    $original_selection = $_GET['original_selection'];
}

for($i = 0; $i < count($thumbArray); $i++)
{
    if($thumbArray[$i] == $original_selection)
        $index = $i;
}       

?>  

<html>
    <head><title>Single</title></head>

    <body>
     <?php

        if(isset($_POST['myNext']))
        {
            echo 'index: '.$index;
            $index++;
        }



    ?>

    <div class = "img"> <img src="<?= $dir.$thumbArray[$index] ?>" alt = "Picture" height = "500" width = "500" /></div>

    <form name="NextForm" method="post">


      <br />

      <input type="submit" name="myNext" value="Next"/>



    </form>


        <h1>hi</h1>





    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to output what $index is before the if(isset($_POST['myNext']))?

You miss the action parameter in the form tag:

```
<form name="NextForm" method="post" action="">
```

^ Doing that will send the form data to the same page.

This seems like very inefficient code I'm allowed to be brutally honest.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($thumbArray); $i++)
{
    if($thumbArray[$i] == $original_selection)
        $index = $i;
}
```

Why are you searching like that? Not only will it continue to search after it finds it's value, but there are already a php function for this, namely [array_search](http://php.net/array_search). Also you don't need to loop like that in php, just use the [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop. If you really had to do what you tried above, you should have used "break;" inside the if.

Instead of this:

```
echo 'index: '.$index;
$index++;
```

You could have just done this:

```
echo 'index: '.$index++;
```

EDIT:

Where do you store the thumbarray? This could all have been made much easier and more efficient if you used a database to store the name of the files and gave them for example a group id number, an id etc.

Comment: Index is whatever picture the user clicks on. It enlarges the selected photo just fine and on the first click of next works. Adding your suggestion to my form didn't fix my issue. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: @Whoppa , I repeat; "Have you tried to output what $index is before the if(isset($_POST['myNext']))?". I ask about this, because this is useful to help you. `var_dump($index);` What happens then? Are you sure it's set? Also you didn't do everything of what I said, had you stored the filenames in a database, you wouldn't have had this problem in the first case.

Comment: @Whoppa some proper debugging would really help solving your problem. Output to screen the variables you use in your code. Backtrack until you figure out what the issue is. If there is something that isn't what you expect it to be, then that's an issue and you got to backtrack until you figure out why it isn't what you think it should be.

Comment: The value of $index depends on what photo is clicked on. If the first photo is clicked on $index is 0, the second photo $index is 1, and so on. If I var_dump($index) I break my code because then php doesn't know what spot in the $thumbArray the photo is located at. And I'm not storing it in a database its just in a directory. What I'm trying to do (i guess rather poorly) is to update the $index each time next is clicked. So once $_POST['myNext'] is set i don't know how to increment  $index when the next button is re-clicked. I hope this clarifies things.

Comment: Do as I said though, debug more, because `isset($_POST['myNext'])` simply doesn't return false if someone submits the form you wrote in your question (at least not if you add the action parameter to the form tag).

Comment: @Whoppa Okay, here's your problem and why I ask you to print $index to screen (debugging), because when you submit that form the only data being passed is myNext=Next. Not what image you are currently viewing etc. Just try to print the index to screen before and after the if(isset($_POST['myNext'])). Why don't you try to print something inside of that if, so you know if it ever reach inside of it or not. According to you it does not, but with the code you've provided I doubt that is true.